# Tight subplots that only contain axes labels on the exterior

Tags: matlab, visualization, axis-labels, subplot, axes

I want to plot a large number of subplots in a mercator projection in a tile based manner. For this purpose I want to keep only the x axis for my bottom line of plots. Here's an example of what I mean:

[image]

My previous efforts are to completely remove the labeling and manually include the labeling, but it also removes the grid which is also important, this works for the most part but is a really dirty method.

My code is as follows:

```matlab
ax = usamap([-62 -60], [-57 -53] );
setm(ax,'MapProjection','mercator')

setm(ax,'mlabelparallel',-90)
setm(ax, 'PLabelLocation', [-60, -61, -62])
setm(ax, 'MLabelLocation', [-56,-55,-54]);
setm(ax,'MLineLocation',1,'PLineLocation',1/3)

setm(ax, 'PLabelRound', 0)
setm(ax, 'MLabelRound', 0)
setm(ax,'Frame', 'off')
```

`setm(ax, 'MLabelLocation', [])` only removes the specification and shows now all ticks instead of removing them.

If there are any other way to accomplish the mercator projection, removing the labeling of the x axis/y axis and keeping the grid?

Comment: It would help if you could provide an example (image) of what you're trying to achieve. Which MATLAB version are you using? Did you try [`stackedplot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stackedplot.html)?

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. I am using the latest 2019b version, here is an example of what I want to accomplish.

https://imgur.com/a/oTe9WUf

Comment: I think there are some FEX submissions that should simplify this task: [ex1](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27991), [ex2](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45380).

Comment: thanks for the reply, my main issue with this approach is, that i need to plot it in a mercator projection or similiar quadratic format.

Comment: You should separate your issues: the first issue, is how to only have axes labels on the external axes. The second issue is how to partition/transform your dataset and plot the individual subplots. From what I understood, your issue was the former. Perhaps it would be a good idea to only focus on one issue per SO question. BTW, you might be able to find some useful information on [gis.se].